# I want to find a program that find the greatest number from five numbers that insert by user (use repetition statement)

Tags: c#, vb.net

```
Console.WriteLine("enter your number : ")
Dim number1, number2, number3, largest As Integer
number1 = 2
number2 = 7
number3 = 14

' if 2 > 0 then largest = 2
If number1 > largest Then largest = number1
' if 7 > 2 then largest = 7
If number2 > largest Then largest = number2
' if 14 > 7 then largest = 14
If number3 > largest Then largest = number3

label1.text = largest
```

Comment: Which repetition statements have you learnt about so far?

Answer (score 1):

Try some formula first.

Assign a default value as the largest value
Let each value entered be tested against the default largest value
If it is larger, then assign the value of the default to the entered value
If it is smaller, ignore it and continue the input
Your final value assigned to the default largest value will be the largest.

Answer (score 1):

So you have a console app and want to ask the user for 5 integers and output the highest?

```
Dim numberList As New List(Of Int32)    
Do
    Dim nextNumber As Int32
    Do 
        Console.writeline("Please enter an integer")
    Loop Until Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLIne(), nextNumber)
    numberList.Add(nextNumber)
Loop Until numberList.Count = 5 
        
' easiest way:
Dim maxNumber = numberList.Max()
 ' learning way:
maxNumber = numberList(0)
For Each num In numberList
    If num > maxNumber Then maxnumber = num
Next
Console.WriteLine($"Max-Number is: {maxNumber}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Math.Max

int number1  = 2, number2  = 7, number3  = 15;

label1.text = Math.Max(Math.Max(number1, number2), number3));

Answer (score 0):

This is a C# example with comments. It will display you higest number entered. It does not keep all the numbers. If you like you like to store all number you can create an array to store them in.

```
        int higestNumber = int.MinValue;//here the higest number willbe held, first value is lowest possible integer
        int newNumber;//temp value for current number eneted by the user

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)//cycle to enter 5 numbers
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter number " + (i+1));// message to the user (i+1) so its starts from 1 and not 0
            newNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());//entering number by the user
            if (newNumber > higestNumber)//checking if the new number is higer then the old one
                higestNumber = newNumber;//storing the new higer number
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Higest number is: " + higestNumber);//displaying higest number`
```

Here is a vb version as well

```
Private Shared Sub Main(ByVal args As String())
Dim higestNumber As Integer = Integer.MinValue 'here the higest number willbe held, first value is lowest possible integer
Dim newNumber As Integer 'temp value for current number eneted by the user
For i As Integer = 0 To 5 - 1 'cycle to enter 5 numbers
    Console.WriteLine("Enter number " & i + 1) ' message to the user (i+1) so its starts from 1 and not 0
    newNumber = Integer.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) 'entering number by the user
    If newNumber > higestNumber Then higestNumber = newNumber 'checking if the new number is higer then the old one
    'storing the new higer number
Next

Console.WriteLine("Higest number is: " & higestNumber) 'displaying higest number
```

End Sub

Comment: ty so much  for help

Answer (score 0):

I used a `List(Of T)`. This is a class available in the .Net framework https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-5.0 It is a bit like an array except you don't have to know the size before you start. You don't have to worry about indexes because the `.Add` method will add at the end of the list. The `T` stands for `Type`, in our case, an `Integer`.

Define a variable to hold the user input.

We want 5 numbers from the user so we set up a loop to run 5 times. (It could be `i = 1 To 5`, just habit that I use `0 To 4`)

The message to write a number will appear 5 times. However, what if the user doesn't enter a number? Our list will only accept `Integer`s. We must test the user input to make sure it is an `Integer`. Use `Integer.TryParse` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-5.0#System_Int32_TryParse_System_String_System_Int32__  We are using the first Overload.

`.TryParse` is a very clever Function. It checks the String input, in our case, `Console.ReadLine`, to see if it can be converted to an `Integer`. If it can the Function returns `True` and Our `Do` loop will end. If `False` the code inside the `Do` loop will run and we ask the user to try again. Note that this does not effect the outer For loop so we will still get 5 numbers.

`.TryParse` does one more thing. When it is successful converting the input `String` to an `Integer`, it puts the value into the second parameter, in our case, an `Integer` called `input`.

The last line of the For loop adds the successfully converted string to the list.

Finally we display the result to the user. I used and interpolated string indicated by the `$`. This allows you to include variables or expressions right in the string as long as they are surrounded by braces. `{ }`

We used an Extension Method of `List(Of T)`, `.Max`. You can see this listed in the link I gave you for `List(Of T)`

```
Sub Main()
    Dim lst As New List(Of Integer)
    Dim input As Integer
    For i = 0 To 4
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a whole number")
        Do Until Integer.TryParse(Console.ReadLine, input)
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry, not a whole number. Try Again.")
        Loop
        lst.Add(input)
    Next
    Console.WriteLine($"The highest number you entered is {lst.Max}")
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

The explanation is longer than the code. Do check out the links. It is good to start to learn how to read Microsoft documentation. I always found the Remarks section and the examples most helpful. If you are working in vb be sure to select it with the first drop down arrow on the right side of the page. This will show the examples in vb.